# Hiding jQuery-ui tooltip which is manually opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using jquery tooltip and at some point am manually showing the tooltip by using this code:

`$("#div").tooltip( "open" );`

After that if i do mouse click on somewhere else in the document means that tooltip is not hiding, its still there in the view, is there any way to hide that tooltip other than using the close method as follows.

`$("#div").tooltip( "close" );`

Comment: what is the requirement to hide it? focus out? please give us more info, I don't understand why you need other way

Comment: Why don't you want to use close method?

Comment: actually am show tooltip on touchend of a div like this $("#div").bind('touchend',function(){$("#div").tooltip( "open" );});
if i tap on that div means tooltip will come in view, i need to hide it when i tap somewhere else out of this div or maybe focus out of that div.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to close any div tooltips opened in the whole document, with a single click, you may try:

```
$(document).click(function() {
  $("div").tooltip("close");
});
```

I'm sure that this is not the best way, but you'd give a little description of what you're doing, so I'm suggesting this based on your needs (close tips by clicking anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could solve your problem. Please give your feedback on this.

```
   $('body *:not(#div)').on{'touchstart', function(){
        $("#div").tooltip( "close" );
        }
    }
```